# Why should we use coded ui when we have Specflow?

Tags: specflow, coded-ui-tests

We have utilized Specflow and WatIn for acceptance tests at my current project. The customer wants us to use Microsoft coded-ui instead. I have never tested coded ui, but from what I've seen so far it looks cumbersome. I want to specify my acceptance tests up front, before I have a ui, not as a result of some record/playback stuff. Anyway, can someone please tell me why we should throw away the Specflow/watin combo and replace it with coded ui?

I've also read that you can combine specflow with coded ui, but it looks like a lot of overhead for something which I am already doing fine in specflow.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a blog post on how to do this you might find useful

http://rburnham.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/bdd-ui-automation-with-specflow-and-coded-ui-tests/

The pro's and con's of Coded UI Test that i can think of is your testing the application exactly how the user will be using it. This is good for acceptance test but it also has its limitations. Its also really good for end to end testing. In the past UI Tests have been know to be fragile. For example when MS created the VS2010 UI almost all of the UI tests broke. The main reason being is the technology change. Coded UI tests do help to limit this from happening by the way it matches a control. It uses more of a probability based match. This mean it will try to find the best match based on the information it has such as control name. For us Coded UI tests was our choice because of technology limitations. Our Legacy app is VB and although CUIT does not work great, i'm in the progress of writing an extension to get better control information, it was still our only choice. Also keep in mind CUIT is new and has its own limitations. You should be prepared to be very structured in the way you lay out your project as maintaining your UIMaps can be a bit of manual work due to the current end to end behaviour in VS2010, for example creating a CUIT from an existing action recording always places the test in a UIMap called UIMap.uitest and there is no way to change that or transfer to another UIMap. If you use multiple ui maps this means you will need to record your steps first and then use them in your test. However being in .net it its still very flexible.

By far the best thing about specflow is its gerkin syntax for readability and living documentation. Normally your testing features or behaviours of your app which is where the value comes from It generally aims the test just below the UI. There is a little less chance of the test breaking when the UI changes here but there. Specflow to me is great when your application is under constant change and you want to ensure existing features remain working. It fits well in a Scrum environment as well where you can write your scenario's as a description about how it should work. One limitation to specflow i can see is its open for interpretation. Because of this it can be easy to write a test that is not very reusable and hard to maintain. I like to use more generic terms to describe my steps like "Log in as User1" instead of "Go to Login Page, Enter Username and Password, Click login". Describing it more granular makes it harder to reuse tightly couples it to the UI. How the login actually work should be up to the code behind not the specflow feature.

Combining the 2 however to us seems more beneficial than just using Coded UI Tests. If we decide to completely change the UI we would at least have the behaviours that are expected stored in our specflow features in a way anyone can understand. In the end you need to consider how the application will evolve and the type of application.